# Initiate Request/Response Pattern Within a Consumer

Tags: masstransit

I'm trying to initiate a Request/Response within a Consumer.Consume method and am struggling to populate the bus parameter.

```
public class DeleteUserConsumer : IConsumer<IDeleteUser>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IDeleteUser> context) 
    {
        var address = "rabbitmq://host/vhost/queue"
        var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        var bus = context.??? // was hoping to get an IBusControl instance from the context - but perhaps this isn't possible?

        IRequestClient<IGetUserDetails,IUserDetails> client = new MessageRequestClient<IGetUserDetails, IUserDetails>(bus, address, timeout);
        var userDetails = await client.Request(new IGetUserDetails() {Name = context.Message.Name});
    }
}
```

Ignoring the arbitrary example, is there any mechanism to get a reference to an instance of IBusControl to pass across to the MessageRequestClient constructor?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following steps to get to a happy place with your code.

First, update your class to accept the `IBus` argument:

```
public class DeleteUserConsumer : 
    IConsumer<IDeleteUser>
{
    IBus _bus;

    public DeleteUserConsumer(IBus bus)
    {
        _bus = bus;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IDeleteUser> context) 
    {
        var address = "rabbitmq://host/vhost/queue"
        var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);

        IRequestClient<IGetUserDetails,IUserDetails> client = new MessageRequestClient<IGetUserDetails, IUserDetails>(_bus, address, timeout);
        var userDetails = await client.Request(new IGetUserDetails() {Name = context.Message.Name});
    }
}
```

Next, update your consumer registration to include the factory method to create the consumer:

```
IBusControl busControl = null;
busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(x =>
{
    x.ReceiveEndpoint("my_service", e =>
    {
        e.Consumer(() => new DeleteUserConsumer(busControl));
    })
})
```

The closure should capture a reference to the variable, and it should work properly to pass in the argument. Then, it should work!